# Javascript JSON problem

Tags: javascript, ajax, json, foreach, cycle

Server returns to the client this JSON:

```
{
    "comments": [
        {
            "id": 99,
            "entryId": 19,
            "author": "Вася",
            "body": "Комент Васи",
            "date": "20.10.2022"
        },
        {
            "id": 100,
            "entryId": 19,
            "author": "n54",
            "body": "w754",
            "date": "21.10.2023"
        }
    ],
    "admin": false
}
```

I am trying to show out it:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    var json = eval("("+xmlhttp.responseText+")");
    for(var comment in json.comments){
        alert(comment["author"]);
    }
}
```

As expected, cycle works 2 times, but this alert shows only "undefined".
But if I try to execute alert(json.admin); it will show false, as planned.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do not use eval. Ever. Use JSON.parse. You can use Crockford's json2 (https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) for cross browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to iterate over the contents in the array you should iterate over the array indexes rather than iterate over the properties in the array,

So use the following code snippet to iterate over the array indexes which is the right thing to do,

```
for(var i = 0; i < json.comments.length; i++){
    alert(json.comments[i]["author"]);
}
```

Iterating over array properties like the following code snippet is not the right way because one of the array properties contains 'remove' function.

```
for(var i in json.comments){
    alert(json.comments[i]["author"]);
}
```

In the above code ***i*** will take values ***0, 1, 2,..., remove function***

Answer (score 1):

You need to do

```
for(var comment in json.comments){
    alert(json.comments[comment]['author']);
}
```

comment is just the index of the array ie 0, 1

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    var json = eval("("+xmlhttp.responseText+")");
    for(var i=0;i<json.comments.length;i++){
        alert(comment[i].author);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your JSON, comments is an array. This is better looped with a numbered index `for`.

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200){
    var json = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText); //See my comment on OP
    for(var i = 0; i < json.comments.length; i++){
        alert(json.comments[i]["author"]);
    }
}
```